# unable to print the jquery template data

Tags: jquery-templates

I am using json to get the request. My response Object format is :

```
[
{"id":3,"name":"Zuned Ahmed"},
{"id":4,"name":"ZunedTWO"},
{"id":7,"name":"TORCH"}
]
```

ajax call is:

```
$.ajax( {
                type : 'GET',
                url : URL,
                async : false,
                dataType : "json",
                success : function(data) {
                    $("#product_data_div").html($("#product_template").tmpl(data));
                }

            });
```

template code is:

```
<div id="product_data_div">
                <script id="product_template" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="product_${id}" name="" value="${id}" class="margin-top10">
                    <label for="product_${id}" class="margin-top10">${name}</label>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </script>
                </div>
```

The data is not showing up ,3 checkbox are shown but no text.

Can any body help me out find the changees.

Comment: can anybody provide some advice where i am going wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is code written in jsp which was using JSTL tag library and for JSP, '$' is special character and it is interpreted by jstl and data is populated on jsp page.

To over come this we have 2 solutions:

1. append special character this way ${'$'}{id}
2. we can also set <%@ page isELIgnored="true"%>

Thanks